# advanced Find and replace for Excel or Notepad++

Tags: microsoft-excel, notepad++, macros, find-and-replace

I have long excel/CSV files and I need to change website links and replace the old format with new format.

The old format is:

```
image.xxxxxxx.com/dff/dfdf/dfd/E/77rerebce9-9er5-434e-a2f8-62e8cd3551ac.jp
```

I need to replace this format with

```
ggggggg.com/upload/77rerebce9-9er5-434e-a2f8-62e8cd3551ac.jpg
```

- `77rerebce9-9er5-434e-a2f8-62e8cd3551ac.jpg` the number of letters of this file is always 40 character.
- `image.xxxxxxx.com/dff/dfdf/dfd/E` may have more directories

How can I do this using Notepad++ or Microsoft Excel?

Comment: Please [edit] the question and give a few more before and after examples as at the moment is not very clear what your requirements are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

e.g. in Notepad++:

- open find-replace dialog (CTRL+H)
- check "regular expression"
- find what:
  `image.xxxxxxx.com.*\/([^\/]+\.jpg)`
- replace to:
  `ggg.com/upload/\1`
- press "replace all"

You can test the regular expression [here](https://regex101.com/r/oNXMwJ/1).